# Solving Gearbox Differential Equations in Python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am working on developing gearbox fault detection algorithm, for that I am working on generating gearbox simulation data.
I am referring this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X08002757

I have taken everything as 0 as initial condition.
Here is my code:

```
def gear_equations(t, ti):

    m1 = 0.96       # Mass of Pinion
    m2 = 2.88       # Mass of Gear
    Cr = 1.6456     # Contact Ration
    Im = 0.0021     # Moment of Inertia of Motor
    Ib = 0.0105     # Moment of Inertia of Load
    I1 = 4.3659e-4  # Moment of Inertia of Pinion
    I2 = 8.3602e-3  # Moment of Inertia of Gear
    f1 = 30         # Input Shaft Frequency
    fm = 570        # Gear Mesh Frequency
    M1 = 11.9       # Input Motor Torque
    M2 = 48.8       # Output Load Torque
    kc = 4.4e4      # Total Stiffness of the Coupling
    cc = 5.0e5      # Damping Coefficient of Coupling
    kr = 6.56e7     # Radial Stiffness of the Bearing
    cr = 1.8e5      # Damping Coefficient of the Coupling
    Rb1 = 0.02834   # Base radius of Pinion
    Rb2 = 0.07160   # Base radius of Gear

    mu = 3.99e-6
    #ct = mu*kt

    cm = 3.533e3
    km = 8.854e8

    y1, y11, y2, y22, theta1, theta11, theta2, theta22, thetam, thetaM, thetab, thetaB = ti
    
    k1, k2 = kr, kr
    c1, c2 = cr, cr
    kp, kg = kc, kc
    cp, cg = cc, cc

    dy1_dt = y11
    dy2_dt = y22
    dtheta1_dt = theta11
    dtheta2_dt = theta22
    dthetam_dt = thetaM
    dthetab_dt = thetaB

    Fk = km*(Rb1*theta1 - Rb2*theta2 - y1 + y2)
    Fc = cm*(Rb1*theta11 - Rb2*theta22 - y11 + y22)

    d2y1_dt2 = (Fk + Fc - k1*y1 - c1*y11)/m1 
    d2y2_dt2 = (Fk + Fc - k2*y2 - c2*y22)/m2
    
    d2thetam_dt2 = (M1 - kp*(thetam - theta1) - cp*(thetaM - theta11))/Im
    d2thetab_dt2 = (M2 - kg*(theta2 - thetab) - cg*(theta22 - thetaB))/Ib

    d2theta1_dt2 = (kp*(thetam - theta1) + cp*(thetaM - theta11) - Rb1*(Fk + Fc))/I1
    d2theta2_dt2 = (Rb2*(Fk + Fc) - cg*(theta22 - thetaB) - kg*(theta2 - thetab))/I2

    return [dy1_dt, d2y1_dt2, dy2_dt, d2y2_dt2, dthetam_dt, d2thetam_dt2, dthetab_dt, d2thetab_dt2, dtheta1_dt, d2theta1_dt2, dtheta2_dt, d2theta2_dt2]

t0 = tuple([0]*12)
t = np.linspace(0, 10, int(8e4))

sol = solve_ivp(gear_equations, (0,10), t0, method="BDF", t_eval=t)
```

I am getting this warning:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars   d2theta1_dt2 = (kp*(thetam - theta1) + cp*(thetaM - theta11) - Rb1*(Fk + Fc))/I1
and then this error:
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Comment: Your solution is blowing up; the second error is almost certainly a consequence of the first, and the first error means one or more components of your system are numerically overflowing to `inf`.  If I run your code with the stopping time set to 2.5e-8, I can already see what looks like the beginning of exponential growth in a couple components.  Are you sure the system is stable?  If so, double-check the code; in particular, check for sign errors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am new to solving ODEs in python, how should I check whether the system is stable? How to set the stopping time.